# Join two (non)paired RDDs to make a DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

As the title describes, say I have two RDDs

```
rdd1 = sc.parallelize([1,2,3])
rdd2 = sc.parallelize([1,0,0])
```

or

```
rdd3 = sc.parallelize([("Id", 1),("Id", 2),("Id",3)])
rdd4 = sc.parallelize([("Result", 1),("Result", 0),("Result", 0)])
```

How can I create the following DataFrame?

```
Id    Result
1     1
2     0
3     0
```

If I could create the paired RDD  [(1,1),(2,0),(3,0)] then `sqlCtx.createDataFrame` would give me what I want, but I don't know how?

I'd appreciate any comment or help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that they have the same partitioner and the same number of elements per partition, you can use the `zip` function, e.g.

```
case class Elem(id: Int, result: Int)
val df = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(rdd1.zip(rdd2).map(x => Elem(x._1, x._2)))
```

Answer (score 2):

So first off, there is an RDD operation called `RDD.zipWithIndex`. If you called `rdd2.zipWithIndex` you would get:

```
scala> rdd2.zipWithIndex collect() foreach println
(1,0)
(0,1)
(0,2)
```

If you wanted to make it look like yours, just do this:

```
scala> rdd2.zipWithIndex map(t => (t._2 + 1,t._1)) collect() foreach println
(1,1)
(2,0)
(3,0)
```

If you really need to zip the two RDDs, then just use `RDD.zip`

```
scala> rdd1.zip(rdd2) collect() foreach println
(1,1)
(2,0)
(3,0)
```

Comment: Nice! very useful transformations! I guess, I should accept Holden's answer since she answered first. Cheers!

Comment: I posted already this solution for DataFrames, maybe up vote this one too! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30304810/dataframe-ified-zipwithindex