# how to carry over last non empty value to subsequent rows using Spark DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I've a sparse dataset like this:

```
  ip,ts,session
  "123","1","s1"
  "123","2",""
  "123","3",""
  "123","4",""
  "123","10","s2"
  "123","11",""
  "123","12",""
  "222","5","s6"
  "222","6",""
  "222","7",""
```

I need to make it dense like this:

```
  ip,ts,session
  "123","1","s1"
  "123","2","s1"
  "123","3","s1"
  "123","4","s1"
  "123","10","s2"
  "123","11","s2"
  "123","12","s2"
  "222","5","s6"
  "222","6","s6"
  "222","7","s6"
```

I know how to do it using RDD - re-partition by ip and within partitionMap groupBy(ip).sortBy(ts).scan()(): scan function will carry over prior calculated value to the next iteration and decide to use prior value or keep current and pass new choice to next "scan" iteration

Now I'm trying to use DataFrame only, without going back to RDD.
I was looking at Window functions, but all I could come up with is first value within group, which is not the same. Or I just do not understand how to create correct range.

Comment: Can you count on the `ts` column as being a sequence number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with multiple self-joins. Basically, you want to create a data set of all the "start session" records (`filter($"session" !== "")`) and then join that against the original data set, filtering out the records where the "session start" was later than the current session (`filter($"ts" >= $"r_ts")`). Then you want to find out the `max($"r_ts")` for each `ip`. The last join is just to retrieve the `session` value from the original data set.

```
data.join(
  data.filter($"session" !== "").select(
    $"ip" as "r_ip", $"session" as "r_session", $"ts" as "r_ts"
  ), 
  $"ip" === $"r_ip"
)
.filter($"ts" >= $"r_ts")
.groupBy($"ip",$"ts")
.agg(max($"r_ts") as "r_ts")
.join(
  data.select($"session",$"ts" as "l_ts"), 
  $"r_ts" === $"l_ts"
)
.select($"ip",$"ts",$"session")
```

BTW, my solution assumes that the column `ts` is something like a transaction sequence -- that it is an incrementing Int value. If it's not, you can use my [DataFrame-ified zipWithIndex solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30304810/dataframe-ified-zipwithindex) to create a column that will serve the same purpose.

Comment: ts is a timestamp in my case, so yes it is increasing

Comment: I think you have an error there: .join(
  data.select($"session",$"ts" as "l_ts"), 
  $"r_ts" === $"l_ts" : this should also use ip as apart of the join, and it should join to first part where you have session and r_ts and ip. But I got the idea! THANKS A BUNCH!

Answer (score 0):

My final code reusing David Griffin idea: dataWithSessionSparse is a starting dataset described in my question

```
val denseSessRecordsOnly = dataWithSessionSparse
  .filter(col("sessionId") !== "")
  .select(col("ip").alias("r_ip"), col("sessionId").alias("r_sessionId"), col("ts").alias("r_ts")) // isolates first records for all sessions

val dataWithSessionDense = dataWithSessionSparse
  .join(denseSessRecordsOnly, col("ip") === col("r_ip")) // explodes each event to relate to all sessions within ip
  .filter(col("ts") >= col("r_ts")) //flters out exploded dataset to have each event to be related to sessions prior or at the time of event
  .groupBy(col("ip"),col("ts")).agg(max(col("r_ts")).alias("r_ts")) //takes sessionId with max ts.
  .join(
    denseSessRecordsOnly.select(col("r_ip").alias("l_ip"),col("r_sessionId").alias("sessionId"),col("r_ts").alias("l_ts")),
    col("r_ts") === col("l_ts") && col("ip")===col("l_ip"))
  .select(col("ip"),col("ts"),col("sessionId"))
```