# How to create index in Spark Table?

Tags: indexing, apache-spark-sql

I know Spark Sql is almost same as Hive.

Now I have created a table and when I am doing Spark sql query to create the table index, it always gives me this error:

> Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: mismatched input '' expecting AS near ')' in create index statement

[image: test table]

The Spark sql query I am using is:

```
CREATE INDEX word_idx ON TABLE t (id)
```

The data type of id is bigint.
Before this, I have also tried to create table index on "word" column of this table, it gave me the same error.

So, is there anyway to create index through Spark sql query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no way to do this through a Spark SQL query, really. But there's an `RDD` function called `zipWithIndex`. You can convert the `DataFrame` to an `RDD`, do `zipWithIndex`, and convert the resulting `RDD` back to a `DataFrame`.

See this **[community Wiki article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30304810/dataframe-ified-zipwithindex)** for a full-blown solution.

Another approach could be to use the
**[Spark MLLib String Indexer](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/ml-features.html#stringindexer)**.

Comment: Yes, I am using zipWithIndex on some RDDs, but for this one, I need to create index on a specific column, zipWithIndex is not very convenient for yes, I need to separate the data first, use zipWithIndex, then join. I am wondering whether there is a simpler way.

Comment: Maybe take a look at the `mLib` `StringIndexer`?

Comment: If you don't need ID to be sequential you could look at monotonically_increasing_id()