# How to Reverse arrangement DataFrame in Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How can I reverse this DataFrame using Scala.
I saw `sort` functions but must specific column, I only want to reverse them

```
+---+--------+-----+
|id |    name|note |
+---+--------+-----+
|1  | james  |any  |
|3  | marry  |some |
|2  | john   |some |
|5  | tom    |any  |
+---+--------+-----+
```

to:

```
+---+--------+-----+
|id |    name|note |
+---+--------+-----+
|5  | tom    |any  |
|2  | john   |some |
|3  | marry  |some |
|1  | james  |any  |
+---+--------+-----+
```

Comment: Do note that in most cases there is no guranteed order of the dataframe which is why you won't find any operation such as reverse (if you sort by a column it's no problem however). See e.g.: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-16207

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a column with increasing id with use of `monotonically_increasing_id()`
and sort in descending order

```
val dff = Seq(
  (1, "james", "any"),
  (3, "marry", "some"),
  (2, "john", "some"),
  (5, "tom", "any")
).toDF("id", "name", "note")

dff.withColumn("index", monotonically_increasing_id())
  .sort($"index".desc)
  .drop($"index")
  .show(false)
```

Output:

```
+---+-----+----+
|id |name |note|
+---+-----+----+
|5  |tom  |any |
|2  |john |some|
|3  |marry|some|
|1  |james|any |
+---+-----+----+
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this:

```
val reverseDf = df.withColumn("row_num", row_number.over(Window.partitionBy(lit(1)).orderBy(lit(1))))
                .orderBy($"row_num".desc)
                .drop("row_num")
```

Or refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30304810/dataframe-ified-zipwithindex) instead of row number.

Comment: It won't work for a large dataset (that's larger than the RAM of the most powerful executor) since it leads to OOME.